# Interaction eventtrigger Tap for listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have template for listboxitem. Template contains checkbox. Always, when I check it, so Tap event is fired. But Tap has to fire only when I select item, no when I check checkbox. I've tried to use SelctionChanged event, and this is working normally. But I want to use Interactions because of mvvm pattern. Here is my xaml code.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstboxDevicePositions" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding DevicePositions}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexDevicePosition, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDevicePosition, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="#709DFF" Margin="1,0,1,2" CornerRadius="2" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="cbxSelected" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtblockBindedAddress" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtblockBindedDate" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Date}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShowDevicePositionCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
```

**EDIT**

Problem is, that checkbox and listbox have Tap event. So when I tap on checkbox event is fired. I want to fire Tap event only when I tap on listboxitem.

Comment: i think You Need to move This Event On CheckBox May It's Work not Sure

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Sounds like you simply need to stop the checkbox from handling mouse/gesture events.
Just set IsHitTestVisible to False on the checkbox.</strike>

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cbxSelected" 
          Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.RowSpan="2" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
```

I realise now that I misread your question...

If you want to be able to check the checkbox without causing the ListBoxItem to be selected, you should handle the Tap event from the CheckBox.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cbxSelected" 
          Tap="cbxSelected_Tap"
          ...
          />
```

...

```
private void cbxSelected_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

By setting Handled = true, you will stop the event from being routed to the ListBoxItem.

Comment: No IsHitTestVisible="false" isn't working. I need to check checkbox, with this property I can't.